# Global variable seen by multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure why the following is happening, I apologize for this, I'm guessing, simple question.

I have the following set in a Global Controller.  I did it this way for a couple reasons, most notably for setting a label on a form.

```
public static string CurrentUsername = "";
```

Now, when I deploy, I am seeing that multiple users are updating the variable and the variable is not user specific, what am I doing wrong here?  I am just trying to store the current user that is using the application.  I tried using session, but I ran into difficulties in certain places.

Comment: if you want to set the variable for user basis, need to make a class, create instantiate and use it

Comment: Because its static - there is only once instance of it.

Comment: Fields and properties that are marked `static` will be shared for all users of your site. You should not use static fields to store "per-user" data. Use the `Session` for that, that basically is its purpose...

Comment: Thanks all. I knew it was a dumb question

Answer (score 2):

Since its static, its created once for all instances of your controller.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static

Comment: Thanks all.  I knew it was a dumb question